# Change image src while waiting for AJAX callback: Only working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a JavaScript / jQuery function which is executed when I click on a button on my page. I also have an `<img>` on the page (id="P34_DOWNLOAD_STATUS_ICON"), its source being initially set to a file called "magnifying_glass.png" in an image directory on the server.
The function starts an AJAX callback and parses its response. When the response is successful, the src of my status img is changed to icon_ok.png, in case of error to icon_err.png. So far so good.

I would also like to change the img source to a GIF right before the AJAX call is executed for the user to see that something is happening. This is the problematic part: In Firefox, everything works as expected, but in any other browser I've tried (Chrome 44, IE 11, Opera 30) the Loading GIF just doesn't show.

Here's the code:

```
function f_getFileFromURL(){

  var IMG_PATH = "<path to images directory>";
  var ICO_LOAD = IMG_PATH + "loading.gif";
  var ICO_ERR = IMG_PATH + "icon_err.png";
  var ICO_OK = IMG_PATH + "icon_ok.png";
  var ICO_SEARCH = IMG_PATH + "magnifying_glass.png";  

  var statusIcon = $("#P34_DOWNLOAD_STATUS_ICON").get(0);

  var url = $v("P34_URL");
  var pPageSubmissionId = $v("pPageSubmissionId");


  try{
    /*Set icon to loading GIF */ 
    statusIcon.src = ICO_LOAD;
    /* also tried this: */
    /*document.getElementById("P34_DOWNLOAD_STATUS_ICON").src = ICO_LOAD;*/


    /*Start AJAX callback */ 
    var responseString = f_execProcess("FETCH_FILE_FROM_WEB", [url,pPageSubmissionId]);
    var responseObj = jQuery.parseJSON(responseString)

    if (responseObj.responseCode == 0){
      /*Call was successful*/ 
      statusIcon.src = ICO_OK;


    }else{
      statusIcon.src = ICO_ERR;
      alert('Error downloading file:"' + responseObj.errorMsg + '"'); 
    }


  }catch(err){ 
    /*Set icon to loading GIF */ 
    statusIcon.src = ICO_ERR;  
    alert('Error downloading file:"' + err + '"'); 
  }
}
```

I noticed that if I don't change the img src to ICO_OK or ICO_ERR after executing the AJAX call, the GIF does show up in every browser. I guess this means that in every browser except Firefox, I have to wait until the function has finished executing to see the effects of changing the img src.

Any advice on how to get this to work in every browser? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you are calling

```
var responseString = f_execProcess("FETCH_FILE_FROM_WEB", [url,pPageSubmissionId]);
```

It will call your URL asynchronously and hence not waiting for next statements which are in queue. To prevent the statements execution before getting the `response` you need to stay there, so use `async:false` or make a callback (in ajax success function) which will change your image source.

Callback example,

```
// function which will change img src, and it is your callback
function changeImgSource(responseString){
    var responseObj = jQuery.parseJSON(responseString);    
    if (responseObj.responseCode == 0){
      /*Call was successful*/ 
      jQuery(statusIcon).attr('src',ICO_OK);
    }else{
      jQuery(statusIcon).attr('src',ICO_ERR);
      alert('Error downloading file:"' + responseObj.errorMsg + '"'); 
    }
}
```

Pass 3 parameter as callback

```
/*Start AJAX callback */ 
var responseString = f_execProcess("FETCH_FILE_FROM_WEB", [url,pPageSubmissionId],changeImgSource);
```

Add this callback function to your `ajax success function` like,

```
function f_execProcess(param_1,param_2,callback){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:param_1,
        data:param_2,
        success:function(data){
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}
```

And try to use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr) for changing src like,

```
jQuery(statusIcon).attr('src',ICO_ERR);
```

Comment: Hi Rohan, thank you for your answer. I should probably mention that I'm using the Oracle APEX development framework. f_execProcess calls the native fuction htmldb_get.get() which actually waits for the call to finish. In any case, in every browser except FF, the image DOES NOT change (i.e. remains magnifying_glass.png) until the callback has finished executing. If the problem were that the function doesn't wait for the call to be executed, I would expect the icon to change immediately to ICO_ERR or ICO_OK. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Try this once `jQuery(statusIcon).attr('src',ICO_ERR);` Make sure your `IMG_PATH` is correct and valid URL( like `var IMG_PATH = "http://localhost/test/";`)

Comment: I tried `jQuery(statusIcon).attr('src',ICO_LOAD);` (as ICO_LOAD is the icon I want to display). Same result: Works perfectly in FF, but doesn't show in other browsers.

Comment: This might be a bit tricky as the application runs only on my corporate intranet. I will try to reproduce the problem on an Apex public workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I think statusIcon is a jQuery object. So you might try (if jQuery version >1.9)

```
statusIcon.prop("src",src);
```

otherwise

```
statusIcon.attr("src",src);
```

Comment: I get "TypeError: statusIcon.attr is not a function" and "TypeError: statusIcon.prop is not a function" :(

Comment: Sorry I forgot to convert into jQuery object. This would be the code: